# Drupal, remove input filter chooser from comment from

Tags: drupal-6

Could somebody tell me how can I remove input filter chooser from comment form in Drupal 6?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Administer > Site Configuration > Input Formats
```

Click configure for each of the formats, and edit who can use the roles as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use jquery.  This is nice if you want more granular control over displaying the comment input filter.   One way to hide it is using the following code:

```
$("label:contains('Filtered HTML')").parent().parent().parent().hide();
```

You can put this in your theme's .js file if you have one.